# MongoDB aggregation/map-reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDB and I need to do an aggregation which seems to me quite difficult. A document looks something like this

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("568192aef8bd6b0cd0f649c6"), 
 "conference" : "IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing", 
 "prism:aggregationType" : "Conference Proceeding", 
 "children-id" : [
    "SCOPUS_ID:84948148564", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84927603733", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84943521758", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84905234683", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84876113709"
 ], 
 "dc:identifier" : "SCOPUS_ID:84867598678"
}
```

The example contains just the fields I need in the aggregation. ***Prism:aggregationType*** can have 5 different values(conference proceeding, book, journal etc.). ***Children-id*** says that this document is cited by an array of other documents(*SCOPUS_ID* is an unique ID for each document).
What I want to do is to group first by ***conference***, then for each ***conference*** I want to know for each ***prism:aggregationType*** how many citing documents are($gt > 0).

For example, lets say there are 100 documents that have the conference from above. These 100 documents are cited by 250 documents. I want to know from all of these 250 documents how many have ***"prism:aggregationType" : "Conference Proceeding"***, ***"prism:aggregationType" : "Journal"*** etc.
An output could look like this:

```
{  
 "conference" : "IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing", 
 "aggregationTypes" : [{"Conference Proceeding" : 50} , {"Journal" : 200}]
}
```

It is not important if it is done with aggregation pipeline or map-reduce.

**EDIT**

Is there any way to combine these 2 into one aggregation:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
 { $match:{
    conference : {$ne : null}
 }},
 {$unwind:'$children-id'},
 {$group: {
   _id: {conference: '$conference'},
  'cited-by':{$push:{'dc:identifier':"$children-id"}}
 }}
 ]);
db.articles.find( { 'dc:identifier': { $in: [ 'SCOPUS_ID:84943302953', 'SCOPUS_ID:84927603733'] } }, {'prism:aggregationType':1} );
```

In the query I want to replace the array from **$in** with the array created with **$push**

Comment: So given the example above as the sole sample document in the collection, will you be expecting the count for `"Conference Proceeding"` to be the same as the size of `"children-id"` array i.e. 5?

Comment: yes, if this document would be the only one to have "conference" : "IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing" then the result will be equal to the array size, but the documents which are citing this document does not necessarily have the same "prism:aggregationType"; but for sure there will be more documents with that conference

Comment: the idea is that you group by **conference**, then you will do an inner join with the ids from the array to get the **aggregationType** of those ids then count each **aggregationType**

Comment: Hi Anderw -it looks like a bigger issue - come to chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104903/mongo-queries-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I wrote in the EDIT section is also the final result I come up with(a little bit modified)

```
db.articles.aggregate([
{ $match:{
  conference : {$ne : null}
}},
{$unwind:'$children-id'},
{$group: {
  _id: '$conference',
 'cited-by':{$push:"$children-id"}
}}
]);
db.articles.find( { 'dc:identifier': { $in: [ 'SCOPUS_ID:84943302953', 'SCOPUS_ID:84927603733'] } }, {'prism:aggregationType':1} );
```

The result will look like this for each conference:

```
{ 
"_id" : "Annual Conference on Privacy, Security and Trust", 
"cited-by" : [
    "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84928151617", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84939229259", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84946407175", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84933039513", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84942607254", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84948165954", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84926379258", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84946771354", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84944223683", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84939169499", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84947104346", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84948764343", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84938075139", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84946196118", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84930820238", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84947785321", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84933496680", 
    "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431"
]
}
```

I iterate through all the documents I get (around 250) and then I use the *cited-by* array inside *$in*. I use index over *dc:identifier* so it works instantly.
*$lookup* could be an alternative to get the things done from aggregate pipeline but packages in R does not support versions above 2.6. 
Thank you for your time anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

```
> db.collections
    .aggregate([
       // 1. get the size of `children-id` array through $project
       {$project: {
             conference: 1, 
             IEEE1: 1, 
             'prism:aggregationType': 1, 
             'children-id': {$size: '$children-id'}
        }},
        // 2. group by `conference` and `prism:aggregationType` and sum the size of `children-id` 
        {$group: {
                 _id: {
                    conference:'$conference', 
                    aggregationType: '$prism:aggregationType'
                    }, 
                 ids: {$sum: '$children-id'}
         }}, 
         // 3. group by `conference`, and make pair of the conference processing ids size and journal ids size 
         {$group: {
               _id: '$_id.conference', 
               aggregationTypes: { 
                           $cond: [{$eq: ['$_id.aggregationType', 'Conference Proceeding']}, 
                                   {$push: {"Conference Proceeding": '$ids'}}, 
                                   {$push: {"Journal": '$ids'}}
                           ]}
         }}
]);
```

Comment: i have version 3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

As we had a chat,

using **$lookup** in aggregation pipeline is unfortunately bonded to mongodb 3.2 which is not a case as R driver can use mongo 2.6 and source documents are in more than one collection.

Comment: I think the "R driver" you are referring to only has a restriction on "authentication types" and is not actually restricted in version, also there are other drivers. Of course `$lookup` is only available since "server version" 3.2.x, and would not be available for 3.0.6 as mentioned by the OP. Nonetheles, this is the "same collection", so `$lookup` is not the thing you would use here, and also this is "additional results", not "related results", as `$lookup` is used for. Also, really a comment and does not attempt to offer a solution.

Comment: yeah  - the main thing is tie to 3.0.6